# Is there a way to add characters in dc.js numberDisplay Class?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I would like to add some text in the numberDisplay function, a little bit like this.

```
    dc.numberDisplay('#duration')
        .group(all)
        .valueAccessor(function (d) { 
            if (xxx) return d.duration + ' [months]';
            else return d.duration + ' [years]'; 
        });
```

> this prints `NaN`

My specific need is that I have a duration number in years, but sometimes —after some crossfiltering— this number gets really low —*e.g.* 0.00002— and that is not understandable so I would like to simplify things for the user and transform that in months or days or even hours.

My first attempt was to split the duration in 4 numbers (years/months/days/hours) and have 4 separate html tags and 4 numberDisplay's.

But that is not necessary if duration = 5 hours, the user will see `0Y, 0M, 0D, 5H`, while `5 hours` would be more clear.

I need to print at least 2 informations: the highest nonzero number and the unit and I cannot manage that.

Another idea: Is there a way to trigger a secondary function after the numberDisplay finished?
This way I could just send basic d.duration in years in the numberDisplay. And have another function transform that afterwards in smaller units.

[EDIT]
`.html()` seems to be build for this, but `one/some/none` do not fit my needs of diferentiating  0.0000002 / 0.0002 / 0.02

Comment: Rather than change the value I think you want to change the [format](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.numberDisplay.html#formatNumber).